# how to subtract a value in a column when user enter a no of seats

Tags: php

I am using php and mysql, My table like this

[image]

if a user enter a time 09:00 and reserve 2 seats and 
if a user enter a time 10:00 and reserve 1 seat so how to subtract value in seats available

[image]

like this

Comment: Show some code, so you can get answer.

Comment: Use UPDATE table SET Field2 = Field2-1 WHERE ID = 'value'.

Comment: UPDATE table SET Field2` = Field2-1 WHERE ID = 'ID' and Field2 !=0 ;

Comment: @jothi, Seat available list may never shows if there is no seats, But good point.

Answer (score 0):

For updating a database table field you can just use `UPDATE` statement. The UPDATE statement is used to update existing records in a table.

For Updating fields you need to set fields for update, In this case you want to decrements a value with the field name `Filed2` as shown in the image. 
So for doing that,You have to SET that filed name as `Field2 = Field2-1`, What this did? This decrements the value from that field by 1.

Example:

```
UPDATE table SET Field2 = Field2-1 WHERE ID = 'your_value'
```

Try this and let me know. For more: [visit - sql_update](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Answer (score 0):

IN PHP CODE -

- First get the seat available from the table and store value in the variable

  ```
  select seats_available from table_name where time = 'time'
  ```
- and then update the row using update statement as below -

  ```
      update table_name set seats_available = $var['seats_available'] - 2 where time='time'
  ```

IN MYSQL QUERY (DIRECTLY)
 - just use update statement 
      update table_name set col_name = 'value' where time='time'